# Why use XXXX_new and XXXX_free over new and delete?

Tags: c++, libssh

While reading into the [libssh library](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html), I saw that they specifically say

> libssh follows the allocate-it-deallocate-it pattern. Each object that you allocate using xxxxx_new() must be deallocated using xxxxx_free()

Is this something that comes from it being a C library rather than a C++ library where new and delete didn't exist or is it a common practice to forget about new and delete and manually create and delete objects using the xxxx_new and xxxx_free pattern?  If it is a common practice what are it's benefits over new and delete and the constructors and destructors that are called?

[EDIT] Added the link to where I read this as an `<a>` tag on "libssh library" for those asking.

Comment: do you have a link to where you read that?

Comment: Besides it being a C interface, the main distinction is that it changes who controls object creation -- the consumer vs the library. With this interface, the library controls more, which gives it more power (e.g. logging, breakpoints, global configuration, avoiding mismatched `new` and `delete` calls from different DLLs, etc.)

Comment: ssh_new pairs with ssh_free, ssh_scp_new pairs with ssh_scp_free, ssh_string_new pairs with ssh_string_free, ssh_event_new pairs with ssh_event_free.  Respectively the allocate and the free functions for session, scp, string and event objects, it isolates the allocator and object implementation details.  The C++ new and delete operators are not useful in a C library.

Comment: So if someone was to write a C++ version of this library (or at least one that wraps around it) would it make sense to stick with the function calling convention or use traditional C++ new and delete along with the appropriate constructors and destructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first glance at the link you provided reveals that `libssh` uses the `xxxx_new()` functions as combined allocator/constructor calls. It's really just a standard naming of factory functions. Likewise, `xxxx_free()` acts as a destructor/deallocator combination.

Combining allocation and construction into a single function call is a good idea whenever a library wants to provide typesafe opaque pointers to its user code: To compile the user code, the compiler only needs to know that the type exists and that it's distinct from any other type. There is no need to have the full `class`/`struct` declaration in a public header.

This approach is not very popular with C++ libraries, because they generally want their objects to behave like any normal C++ object (which means that the pointers/references must not be opaque to the compiler). But if a library provides a C interface, such factory functions make it unlikely that you get weird errors due to users passing in pointers to uninitialized objects (forgotten constructor call), or screwing up the allocation of your objects.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this something that comes from it being a C library rather than a C++ library where new and delete didn't exist

Most probably yes. There's often need for more initializations done than plain memory allocation as available with `malloc()` in c code. It's similar as `new` calls constructors of `class`/`struct` instances created.

> or is it a common practice to forget about new and delete and manually create and delete objects using the xxxx_new and xxxx_free pattern?

No, that's not common practice in c++.

The way to deal with dynamically allocated instances and ownership is to use the functions and smart pointer classes from the standard c++ [**Dynamic memory management**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) utilities.